# call action method in implementation file

Tags: ios, objective-c, action

I have an action method in the implementation file called in response to a user action.  I'd now like to call it from another method but am having trouble with syntax:

How would I call this from inside another method?

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender { //open method

[self login]; gives no visible interface error
```

Comment: do you want to call a method within its method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the sender is self, [self sender:self]: turned out to work.

Answer (score 1):

Because this method has one parameter sender:

```
[self login:nil];
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I do very strongly tend *not* to do this at all.

I wouldn't have an IBAction named "login" in the first place. I'd have an IBAction named "loginButtonPressed:" which may call a method named login. And I might have other code also calling the method login.

IBAction should be reserved for handling the case that the user pressed a button, for example. It's pure user interface handling the button. It shouldn't do things like logging in, only call a method that does it if needed. An IBAction would assume that sender is the button that was pressed. Your loginButtonPressed: IBAction might for example change the name of the button that was pressed. If you call login from other places then the button is likely not affected, so you shouldn't call the IBAction but a separate piece of code.

Comment: fair enough.  Was looking for a quick fix but this is probably a better way to do things